# Import with and without main scope

Tags: python, python-import

I have two files, `app.py` and `database.py` in the same directory. 
Primarily I have the following code snippets:

**app.py**

```
import database
db = "demo_database"
print(database.show_database_information())
```

**database.py**

```
from app import db
database_username = "root"
database_password = "password"
def show_database_information():
    information = {}
    information["filename"] = db
    information["username"] = database_username
    information["password"] = database_password
    return information
```

When I try to run `app.py` I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "K:\PyPrac\circular_call\app.py", line 1, in <module>
    import database
  File "K:\PyPrac\circular_call\database.py", line 1, in <module>
    from app import db
  File "K:\PyPrac\circular_call\app.py", line 3, in <module>
    print(database.show_database_information())
AttributeError: module 'database' has no attribute 'show_database_information'
```

Then I updated `app.py` and included `__main__` check like below:

**app.py**

```
import database
db = "demo_database"
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(database.show_database_information())
```

Now it runs smoothly without any error.

I have several questions,

1. What is name of the error occurred in first scenario? Need explanation.
2. Why it runs after including `__main__` scope?
3. What is the better approach of doing operations like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Man!! You are creating a circular moment. Let me tell how.

```
import database  # from app.py
```

But from `database.py` you imported db from app. That is creating a circular moment.

On the other hand,

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

this is making you `database.py` as a name of the module instead of `__main__` that's why it's working. Nothing magical :)

*UPDATE*: Placed `from app import db` this line inside the function `show_database_information()`
This is the HOTFIX for you.

Comment: I know it is creating ```circular import``` but how is it resolved using main scope?

Comment: @arsho I have updated my answer. I hope it will help you.

Comment: It it a hot fix but now the function is called twice. ```{'filename': 'database.sqlite', 'username': 'root', 'password': 'password'}
{'filename': 'database.sqlite', 'username': 'root', 'password': 'password'}``` Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 2):

What I can understand are as below's. Maybe someone more expert can elaborate !

1. Import error.
2. `if __name__ == '__main__':` This condition is used to check whether a python module is being run directly or being imported.
3. If a module is imported, then it's `__name__` is the name of the module instead of main. So, in such situations it is better to call `if __name__ == '__main__':`